# How to use regex to match path on my site, conditionally containing a specific subdirectory?

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that evaluates to true only if the following condition applies given a string.

String should contain:

`mystring` or `mystring/anystring/usa` but it CANNOT contain `mystring/anystring`

Basically if mystring is followed by anything after it which ends in `usa` the string is good, otherwise it is not.

some examples:

```
mysite/shoes/usa                  #allowed

mysite/shoes/mexico               #not allowed

mysite/clothes/usa                #allowed

mysite                            #allowed

mysite/color/japan                #not allowed

mysite/fancycolor/usa/california  #allowed
```

Comment: can `anystring` contain a `/`? Please include in your question, 3 to 5 different examples and your expected outcome.

Comment: i added examples and yes / are allowed

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten my answer and added a few new strings to your sample set to show some separation between Sergey's pattern and my pattern.

```
mysite/something/usa/              #edge-case, to be determined by OP
mysite//usa                        #edge-case, assumed to be fail
mysite/shoes/usa                   #pass
mysite/shoes/mexico                #fail
mysite/clothes/usa                 #pass
mysite/                            #edge-case, to be determined by OP
mysite                             #pass
anothersite/path/usa               #fail
mysite/color/japan                 #fail
mysite/fancycolor/usa/california   #pass
mysite/fancy/color/usa/california  #assumed to be pass based on comment
```

My pattern:  [Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/rXD9Fk/1)

```
~^mysite(?:/.+?/usa(?:/.+)?)?$~  #234 steps
```

My pattern only matches on strings that start with `mysite`, and doesn't match strings that end with a slash, nor on strings that contain an empty directory.

Sergey's pattern:  [Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/rXD9Fk/2)

```
#^\w+(?:/.*/usa(?:/.*)?)?$#  #218 steps
```

Sergey's pattern matches on strings regardless of sitename, trailing slashes (except on `mysite/`), and empty directories.

When selecting the best pattern for your task, you should judge patterns by this hierarchy:

1. **Accuracy** - Pattern steps and shortness are irrelevant if it doesn't do the job.
2. **Efficiency** - Minimizing steps is how you know you have the best pattern.
3. **Brevity** - When there is a tie between two patterns based on Accuracy and Efficiency, then Brevity should break the tie.

If neither of our patterns are exactly what you are looking for, you should ethically comment to both of us so that we can adjust our answers.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, one more thing:  can i stack two different patterns to say condition 1 and/or condition 2 will evaluate to true?

Comment: @bobdabelina If `usa` is always the 2nd subdirectory in the string, then I have been misinformed by your comment and I'll be able to swap back my negated character class where a dot is now being used (boosting my patterns efficiency).  Feedback on the edge-cases in my answer would be helpful for Sergey, me, and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `#^\w+(?:/.*/usa(?:/.*)?)?$#`

> Example below uses multiline mode

Input:

```
mystie/shoes/usa
mysite/shoes/mexico
mysite/clothes/usa
mysite
mysite/color/japan
mystie/fancycolor/usa/california
```

Output:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-16    `mystie/shoes/usa`
Match 2
Full match  37-55   `mysite/clothes/usa`
Match 3
Full match  56-62   `mysite`
Match 4
Full match  82-114  `mystie/fancycolor/usa/california`
```

RegEx101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jyyBxU/3